# R skipping last element in for loop using seq_along

Tags: r, for-loop, sequence

I have the following code:

```
for(j in seq_along(nums)){
      d = dist(nums[j], average)
      print("nums[j]")
      print(nums[j])
      print("dist:")
      print(d)
      if(farthest < d){
        print("farthest = true")
        farthest <- nums[j]
      }
    }
    print("farthest")
    print(farthest)
```

where dist(x, y) returns abs(x-y) and nums is as follows:

```
nums <- c(224, 352, 320, 352, 352, 352, 223)
```

When I run this, it makes 224 the farthest.  The program is calculating the distance for 223.  It gives me a number larger than the distance to 224, however it never assigns 223 to farthest.  I'm unsure of why this is happening...

Comment: The initial value for farthest is 0 and the initial value for the average is 310.7143

Comment: to reproduce your code, we need  your objects (and any packages you've loaded). The call to `dist` isn't going to produce anything meaningful unless it comes from a package that has something other than `stats:dist`.

Comment: dist is a function I created that just returns the absolute value of the first number minus the second number

Comment: please include definitions for any user defined functions, and values for all the objects you're using when you ask a stack overflow question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two different types of values.  `farthest` is a number from `nums`, but `d` is a distance.  You want to use this instead,

```
nums <- c(224, 352, 320, 352, 352, 352, 223)
average <- mean(nums)
farthest <- average
for(j in seq_along(nums)){
  d = abs(nums[j]-average)
  if(abs(farthest-average) < d){
    print("farthest = true")
    farthest <- nums[j]
  }
}
farthest
```

I hope this helps!

## EDIT:

Realistically, you should use something like this,

```
max.ind <- which.max(abs(nums - average))
nums[max.ind]
```

Comment: Yes. THIS (the edit) is how you should find value with the maximum residual.